# How can I define this restriction in R

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing

545 observations of young working males in the U.S. with some
professional and personal characteristics Variables are as follows:
logwage: logarithm of per hour wage rate;
union: dummy variable, 1 if union member;
mar: dummy variable, 1 if married;
school: year of schooling;
exper: experience in years;
black: dummy variable, 1 if black;
hisp: dummy variable, 1 if Hispanic.

logwagei = 0 + school + exper + union + mar + black + hisp + e

We would like to explain log wages from other variables using the model below:
We extend the model by allowing for the possibility that black union members benefit more
from union membership than non-black union members. How can I Estimate this extended model and
test this hypothesis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is add another variable called an interaction term, which is the product between union and black, called, e.g. `union*black`, and if its regression coefficient value is positive and it's significant (p-value<0.05), then black union members benefit more than non-union blacks.  In fact, the average log(wage) for union blacks will be equal to $\beta_0 + \beta_{black} + \beta_{union*black}$, whereas the average loq(wage) for non-union blacks will simply be $\beta_0 + \beta_{black}$.

Comment: thank you so much, it worked